# Red Had Central (JBOSS) toolbar eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jboss, toolbar

My problem is visible at the image on the link :

[Red Hat Central JBOSS Toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1Wv6.png)
Each time that I open my eclipse a new icon of red hat central jboss appears on my toolbar and I dont know how  remove this toolbar or the new icons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Window > Perspective > Customize Perspective > Toolbars, then uncheck what you don't want to see.